# Function conditionally runs async code, but needs to be run sync at other times. How to keep it DRY?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-next

Let's say I have this function, `doSomeThing()`, and it conditionally runs some very expensive code in a worker thread (async), but most of the time it needs to run sync.

Is there any way I can use this async function synchronously? I think no.

**So what other options do I have besides creating two virtually identical functions that differ only in being sync vs async methods?** Is there some DRYer alternative I'm overlooking?

```js
async function doSomeThing(input, shouldDoExpensiveStuff) {
  let output = parseInt(input)

  // ... A lot of shared logic

  if (shouldDoExpensiveStuff) {
    output = await offloadToWorker(input);
  } else {
    output += 1;
  }

  // ... A lot of other shared logic

  return output;
}
```

I know I can move a lot of the shared logic to individual functions that both the new `doSomeThingSync` and `doSomeThingAsync` could share, but it really seems very suboptimal and tedious, and I may need to do this with a number of functions.

**I control the JS execution environment, so browser compatibility is not a concern. Any fancy ECMA magic via Babel is fair game.**

Comment: Is there a specific reason to run synchronously? I mean: when you execute the async function, and it doesn't need to do the expensive stuff, it's almost as fast as a synchronous function, and the function calling this function doesn't care, since it expects a promise to be returned anyway, and it will simply act on that promise. Which is quite clean code I think.

Comment: Good question. The reason is that a third party library is the caller and the caller isn't an `async function`. So the result of a call to a function that returns a promise results in the stored value being the pending promise, rather than the intended result.

Comment: sounds like you already have it figured out. move all your shared logic to shared functions.

Comment: Not as DRY as I would hope when I have to do this for probably no less than five functions that will all be duplicated and identical except for a tiny conditional `await`. That's a lot of repeating yourself. If it's unavoidable so be it, but if there's a better way I'd sure like to know, hence my question.

Comment: But shouldn't the third party know the signature of the function it calls. When you implement your suggestion (2 functions, one async one not), the third party should also know which one to call. If the third party function expects a synchronous result, than you cannot run an async worker in your function and use that result.

Comment: The function is called from a third party that won't tolerate async, and separately in another context where async is fine. The `await` is only called from the async-aware caller.

Comment: @Slbox That sounds like you really have two separate functions that do different things and are called in different places (one does expensive stuff, the other does not). Can you please post the concrete code you're dealing with? What exactly does the shared code do, how does it interact with the `input` and `output`? Why do you have so many function that follow this pattern, do they all do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to make the same function return either immediately or asynchronously:

```js
const fn = sync => sync
  ? 'foo returned immediately'
  : new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('bar returned after 1 second'), 1000));

const main = async () => {
  const foo = fn(true);
  console.log(foo); // foo returned immediately
  const bar = await fn(false);
  console.log(bar); // bar returned after 1 second
}

main();
```